# Switch to another object of same tensor 'rank' to introduce a different class of multilinear maps

Tags: tensors, multilinear-algebra

My idea is very simple: we know that 'tensors' are a *class* of multilinear maps or object that "maps" in a (multi-)linear manner geometric vectors, scalars.

> a multilinear map is a function of several variables that is linear separately in each variable. More precisely, a multilinear map is a function [....]

I want to do same thing but **without choosing the same (multi-)linear** ***manner*** because I want object

`a)` with same 'rank' or 'level' of tensors
`b)` but objects that maps in a **different** (multi-)linear manner the same geometric vectors, scalars because I want **c)**
`c)` same absolute values, same properties, same objects but that returns different *side effects* but objects that, mathematically, have the same properties

[PICTURE EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSryr.png)

In practice it is as if I did the **same** things, but acting like from an imaginary 'mirrored inverted' space, in this way I obtain the opposite effects but preserving all the mathematical properties and therefore, seen from the outside, it seems that nothing changes, in truth, changes or reverses the *experience* of such objects ***in the moment*** in which the experience takes place, it is not to be considered as an event in the sense of "first" because mathematically speaking, we do not have any previous information that can generate a logical state of the system.

Comment: I will be honest, I don't understand the question. What is meant by "side effects"? What is meant by "multilinear manner" or "linear manner"? What is meant by "geometric vectors"? What is meant by "same absolute values"? Don't vectors not have absolute values? It sounds like you want the same thing as tensors ("objects that mathematically have the same properties") but with "different side effects". If they have the same properties, then how could they behave differently? There are many different definitions of "tensor" other, some more general than others, this has confused me a lot.